# change the height of a rows in excel when hundreds have been set to 0

Tags: excel, height, row

I have an excel spreadsheet with a list of hundreds of users. A lot of the rows have been set to height 0. I want to set all of them to the same value so I can see all of them. I'd rather not have to go through every row and drag the ones with height 0 down so I can see them.

What do I do?

Comment: This is clearly not a programming question. I suggest to migrate to superuser.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mark all cells and double click when the resize icon is visible over the columns.

Comment: saved my time, both auto fit and manual height not worked...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using 2003 or 2007:

1. Highlight all of the rows.
2. Right-click over top of one of the row numbers.
3. Click the Row Height menu item and set it to your desired height.

Answer (score 1):

Select any cell in the data range, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>(apply data filter).

All rows with zero row height will appear.
Can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to trigger data filter off.

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.